# What's the advantage of splitting a mysql table into smaller ones without physical distribution?

Tags: mysql, performance, database, sharding

I've seen such design in my company.

A big mysql table is split into tens of smaller ones of identical schema on the same server in the same db, without any physical distribution, no *innodb_file_per_table*, no partitioning, etc. The data is distributed evenly and the read/write access pattern is uniform across all tables.

What's advantage of doing so performance-wise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your reads/writes are distributed evenly, I think there's no performance advantage. If you were write heavy and writing to, for example, just 2-3 of the tables - then you could benefit (see slides 28-34 of [this](http://www.slideshare.net/bluesmoon/scaling-mysql-writes-through-partitioning-3397422) presentation).

A few ideas about operational benefits:

- It'll be easier to scale out/shard once there's too much data or too much traffic.
- Depending on how your backups are made, it might be quicker to recover something if you can determine in which of the tables lost data was located.

**Edit:** one more thought: if the queries are executed in parallel, there might be performance benefits - you can get more IOPS from your RAID, and better localisation of multi-core system if the working set fits in the memory.

Comment: Thanks pQd, I see several operational benefits too. One of my colleague suggests that splitting can make the index B-tree smaller and make query cache last longer. But I think the saving is too trivial to make a difference. On the other hand, more tables also add more overheads.

Comment: Not to mention complicating every single query.

Comment: i got one more idea - i've edited the answer.

Comment: One more to add; locks (say, from an `ALTER TABLE`) will be more localized.